# link_to text - using ruby code for html text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want the Link text on my view to display as Hospital, Country.  Country is a guidelines attribute so I need to be able to access guidelines.country from 'hospital' and display it

e.g. Get Well Hospital, Sickland

I'm not sure how to code this correctly.  At the moment in my view file I have

```
<% @list.each do |hospital| %>

        <tr class="tablerow">
            <td><%= link_to (hospital, country), :action => :topichospital, :hospital => hospital, :country=>country %></td>
        </tr>
```

It worked when I just had, but I'm not sure how to add the country too

```
 <% @list.each do |hospital| %>

            <tr class="tablerow">
                <td><%= link_to hospital, :action => :topichospital, :hospital => hospital %></td>
            </tr>
```

my listhospital action in guidelines_controller.rb is

```
def listhospital
    @list = Guideline.order(:hospital).uniq.pluck(:hospital)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @guidelines }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Where is the `country` variable coming from? It's probably not stored in `@list` as i'm guessing that `@list` is just an array of hospital names.

Comment: aha!  You are right.  I have added my action in the controller.  @list is just an array of hospitals so how would I access guidelines.country from this (both country and hospital are attributes of guidelines models)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your link_to to

```
<%= link_to "#{hospital}, #{country}", { :action => :topichospital, :hospital => hospital, :country=>country } %>
```

This will convert the first parameter passed to string.  I'm not sure how rails interprets `(hospital, country)` in a link_to when passed as the first parameter but this will make sure to call the `to_s` methods for each.

UPDATE: IIRC, you can use `pluck` to combine attributes

```
# postgre
@list = Guideline.order(:hospital).uniq.pluck("hospital || ', ' || country")

# mysql
@list = Guideline.order(:hospital).uniq.pluck("CONCAT(hospital, ', ', country)")
```

then you can just use `link_to hospital` in the view.

UPDATE: This is becoming a bit of a hack. I suggest you change the controller to

```
@list = Guideline.select('hospital, country').order(:hospital).uniq
```

Then in your view

```
<% @list.each do |guideline| %>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td><%= link_to "#{guideline.hospital}, #{guideline.country}", { :action => :topichospital, :hospital => guideline.hospital, :country => guideline.country }%></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes, this has solved that problem.  as you can see from my edit above, the other issue is that I need to work out how to access country from the list of hospitals...

Comment: that works perfectly in the sense that it displays in the view correctly.  But it's posing a problem for what it's actually linking to.  I want it to display like this on the page but when it load the link it needs to just link to /guidelines/topichospital?hospital=Hospital+Name rather than /guidelines/topichospital?hospital=Hospital+Name&country

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
<%= link_to "#{hospital}, #{country}", :action => :topichospital, :hospital => hospital, :country=>country %>
```

You could also pass a block to `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to :action => :topichospital, :hospital => hospital, :country=>country do %>
  <%= hospital %>, <%= country %>
<% end %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to